Unity Null reference exception when referring to Serialized GameObject in another class
Edit: I know this looks like a duplicate, but I understand that a Nullreference exception happens as I access an object that hasn't been set, or is null. However, I simply don't understand why any of the variables in the following line could be 'null', as I have set each of them.
I'm getting several nullreference exceptions, which I have traced down to this line of code here:
RightHandWeaponSlot.WeaponModel = Weapon;
The GameObject in question is defined in  void Start:
Weapon = GameObject.Find("SM_Wep_Sword_01");
I have subsequently assigned a GameObject, in this case a model to the serialized field in the editor.
However, Unity still passes a Nullreference exception.
Here is the first bit of the PlayerWeaponSlots.cs class
public class PlayerWeaponSlots : MonoBehaviour
{
    private WeaponSlot LeftHandWeaponSlot;
    private WeaponSlot RightHandWeaponSlot;

    private DamageCollider LeftHandDamageCollider;
    private DamageCollider RightHandDamageCollider;

    private GameObject Weapon;
    
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Before start");
        Weapon = GameObject.Find("SM_Wep_Sword_01");
        Debug.Log("GameObject name: " + Weapon.name);
        RightHandWeaponSlot.WeaponModel = Weapon;
        Debug.Log("WeaponModel Set" + RightHandWeaponSlot.getWeaponModel().name);
        //LeftHandDamageCollider = LeftHandWeaponSlot.getWeaponModel().GetComponent<DamageCollider>();
        RightHandDamageCollider = RightHandWeaponSlot.getWeaponModel().GetComponent<DamageCollider>();
    }

And here is the WeaponSlot class itself:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WeaponSlot 
{
    public GameObject WeaponModel = null;

    public void setWeaponModel(GameObject Weapon)
    {
        this.WeaponModel = Weapon;
    }

    public GameObject getWeaponModel()
    {
        return WeaponModel;
    }
}

You'll notice i've set an accessor and mutator function even though the variable itself is Public, and even set it null at the start, but nothing really seems to work. I'm thinking that some sort of mistake in setting up the classes may have caused some variable to be set to null, but I can't figure out how.

Per the edit: RightHandWeaponSlot and RightHandWeaponSlot are what's null here, you never assign them. When trying to find the cause of an NRE, look for the dots: NREs (typically) happen when you use the dot operator on a null value. In your case (RightHandWeaponSlot.WeaponModel = Weapon;), the dot operator is only acting on RightHandWeaponSlot, so that is what's null here. Just assign to it with new WeaponSlot() beforehand.
